# NoClassDefFoundError at AppModule.provideViewModelFactories(AppModule.kt)

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, dagger-2, viewmodelproviders

I am facing this crash only on Kitkat device. My logcat is below. Crashed at `getViewModel`

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics
       at com.transferhome.di.AppModule.provideViewModelFactories(AppModule.kt)
       at com.transferhome.di.AppModule_ProvideViewModelFactoriesFactory.provideViewModelFactories(AppModule_ProvideViewModelFactoriesFactory.java:34)
       at com.transferhome.di.DaggerAppComponent.getViewModelProviderFactory(DaggerAppComponent.java:281)
       at com.transferhome.di.DaggerAppComponent.access$3500(DaggerAppComponent.java:124)
       at com.transferhome.di.DaggerAppComponent$SplashActivitySubcomponentImpl.injectSplashActivity(DaggerAppComponent.java:920)
       at com.transferhome.di.DaggerAppComponent$SplashActivitySubcomponentImpl.inject(DaggerAppComponent.java:916)
       at com.transferhome.di.DaggerAppComponent$SplashActivitySubcomponentImpl.inject(DaggerAppComponent.java:909)
       at dagger.android.DispatchingAndroidInjector.maybeInject(DispatchingAndroidInjector.java:113)
       at dagger.android.DispatchingAndroidInjector.inject(DispatchingAndroidInjector.java:134)
       at dagger.android.AndroidInjection.inject(AndroidInjection.java:63)
       at dagger.android.support.DaggerAppCompatActivity.onCreate(DaggerAppCompatActivity.java:41)
       at com.transferhome.commons.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.kt:41)
       at com.transferhome.splash.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.kt:38)
```

where Splash

```
class SplashActivity : BaseActivity() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: SplashViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        viewModel = getViewModel()

        viewModel.onMoveToNext.listen(this) {
            Handler().postDelayed({
                openActivityAndClearTask(it)
            }, 2000)
        }
    }
}
```

BaseActivity.kt

```
abstract class BaseActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var factories: ViewModelProvider.Factory

    inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> getViewModel(): T {
        return ViewModelProviders.of(this, factories)[T::class.java]
    }
}
```

where AppModule.kt

```
@Module
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideViewModelFactories(viewModels: Map<Class<out ViewModel>,
            @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>):
            ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        return object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
            override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
                val factory = viewModels[modelClass]?.get() ?: error(
                    "No factory provided against ${modelClass.name}"
                )
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                return factory as T
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
class App : DaggerApplication() {

    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder().addContext(this).build()
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        MultiDex.install(this)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this happens only on Kitkat, then it's probably a multi-dexing issue.

You should do the following:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

in AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name="com.acme.myapp.CustomApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And in CustomApplication:

```
public class CustomApplication extends Application {
  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
     super.attachBaseContext(base);
     MultiDex.install(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have added my Application class . See EDIT section in Question. I have to extend it with Dagger

Comment: @XarEAhmer you need to move `MultiDex.install(this)` into `attachBaseContext` instead of calling it after `super.onCreate()`. Theoretically it would also work if you call `MultiDex.install(this)` ***before*** `super.onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've [configured Kotlin in Android project](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#targeting-android) in a right way:

1. `kotlin-android` Gradle plugin is added to the build:

   ```
   plugins {
       id("com.android.application")
       kotlin("android") // This one is important
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Standard library dependency is included:

   ```
   dependencies {
       ...
       implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk7", KotlinCompilerVersion.VERSION))
       ...
   }
   ```

Take a look at a sample project in [this repo](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples/blob/master/samples/hello-android/app/build.gradle.kts#L29).

Comment: kotlin configure correctly and issue only comes on Kitkat devices.

Comment: Which `kotlin-stdlib` artifact are you using? Probably KitKat needs `kotlin-stdlib`, not `kotli-stdlib-jdk7`

Comment: I am using kotlin-stdlib-jdk7